# Different lock passwords

Tags: macos, password

Is there an anyway I can have two different passwords for when the computer is locked (after being in standby) and for the main User password?

I prefer to have a more complicated password for my user and settings but when I for example close my computer for a short while I would like to have to enter a more simple password. Is this possible in some way?

Comment: Some says that you should use a standard session with a simple password and use the admin rights of another session in order to be safe

Comment: @Samoth with a standard sessions being an user account without admin rights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create two accounts. One with administrator rights, and the other one without.

There's no other way around as an User can only have one password (like... **everywhere**).

You just have to be aware that the standard-user cannot access the administrator files. But you can set it up so you can read the standard folders as administrator. So you don't have to switch between users if you like a file which has been placed on the other account.